# Call with skype within my IOS app and then return

Tags: ios, skype

I am developing an iPad app and want to make a call using Skype. I have successfully launched Skype client using an example from Skype with the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"skype:echo123?call"]];
```

which can be found here http://developer.skype.com/skype-uris/skype-uri-tutorial-ios.

I have also read about Skype Buttons, which Skype provides for placing in a webpage and email, but cant find out how to place then in an app, if it's even possible.

When call ends, I want to return to my app. Any information guiding me in the right direction is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications on iOS do support going back to your application after you launch them. For example, Chrome supports this via the x-callback-url scheme: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/ios-links

Unfortunately, Skype does not seem to be among the apps supporting this approach: http://x-callback-url.com/apps/

This likely means you're out of luck. Sorry!